# Pointer to object as argument of a constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

Okay, so let's say I have some random abstract base class `Base` and I have a class `Foo` which contains a pointer to this base class as a datamember. So

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(Base*);

    private:
        Base* ptr;
}
```

Now the reason I use a pointer to the base class is because I want to be able to choose which derived class my `Foo` object has a pointer to. Now the tricky part is, to me, the implementation of the constructor for `Foo`.

If I do it like this

```
Foo::Foo(Base* _ptr)
{
    Foo::ptr = _ptr;
};
```

it would be possible for the user to adjust the object pointed to by `Foo::ptr` since `_ptr` will still exist after the constructor has finished. I cannot make the object pointed to by `_ptr` constant because `Foo::ptr` needs to update itself regularly. Now I was thinking about adding a line `_ptr = NULL` at the end of the constructor, but that could be dangerous as well, since the user could try to dereference `_ptr`.

The only way I can think of to make this work is to make a copy of the object pointed to by `_ptr` and initializing `Foo::ptr` to the address of that copy. But then the object pointed to by `_ptr` would need to have a member function `Clone()` or something similar because I can't call the copy constructor for an object of which I don't know the class at compile-time.

So is there any elegant way of doing this if there is no `Clone()`? Or is that really the only possibility?

Comment: If you use C++11 you could solve this using move-semantics.

Comment: Adding "_ptr = NULL" wouldn't do anything, since "_ptr" is passed by value into the constructor.

Comment: What's wrong with a `clone` method?

Comment: @DavidBrown I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with it, but it does mean the user would have to clean up their own mess, i.e. they would have to delete `_ptr` themselves. I don't know why but it just doesn't really sit well with me. Maybe I'm wrong and the `Clone()` method is fine but I'd like to know the alternatives nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct from a `unique_ptr`. That way your user has no access to the pointer after it has been used in the creation of a `Foo` object (unless he really wants to and uses `get`).

e.g.

```
#include <memory>
struct Bar {};

struct Foo {
  Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar>&& ptr) : ptr_(std::move(ptr)) {}
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> ptr_;
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> tt(new Bar());
  Foo f(std::move(tt));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So this would still work with `std::unique_ptr<DerivedFromBar> tt(new DerivedFromBar());` in the `main()` function? And the user would then need to know they have to use a `unique_ptr`? Or is there an implicit cast possible from a regular pointer to a `unique_ptr`? I'd think not.

Comment: @Wouter `unique_ptr<DerivedFromBar>` converts to `unique_ptr<Bar>`. The point of `unique_ptr` here is that you clearly state ownership at every point in time. The user constructs it, uses it, and as soon as it used to construct a `Foo` he relinquishes ownership by using `move` on it.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I meant to say `std::unique_ptr<Bar> tt(new DerivedFromBar());`, but I see. So `unique_ptr` acts like a regular pointer (with explicit ownership at all times), but the cast from regular to `unique_ptr` I asked about probably doesn't exist, right? Since there's no way to check if it's the only pointer to that object.

Comment: @Wouter You do not necessarily need to `new` the pointer at the time of `unique_ptr` construction, but can construct the `unique_ptr` later from an already assigned pointer. Although there is no implicit conversion to a `unique_ptr`. That would be highly dangerous. In this solution your client is actively aware of giving up control.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using smart pointers. That way, ownership is assigned to the smart pointer implementation.